# Performance-wise,algorithmic complexity-wise which of the following two JS fucntion for capitializing the first letter of a string is better and why?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

Consider the below two functions

```
a) this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.substring(1);

b) this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
```

The code is basically capitializing the first letter of a string.

e.g.

```
var name ="test name";
//var capitializeFirstLetter = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
var capitializeFirstLetter = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
alert(capitializeFirstLetter);
```

**Output:** Test name

Performance-wise,algorithmic complexity-wise which is better and why?

Any thing more better or more optimized ?

Thanks

Comment: optimized for what? The difference will be minimal?

Comment: Agree, but want to know still which method is better?

Comment: In your example `test name` becomes `Test name`, not `Test Name`

Comment: I'd suggest using jsperf.com to compare the two but unfortunately it's down at the moment due to spam. Microbenchmarking is not particularly useful though but that is how I'd answer your question. Test it.

Comment: @Cymen,Where is the test link?

Comment: Without GZIPing, `slice` will save you 4 bytes over `substring`. I doubt you will find much difference in the performance of the 2. I didn't in my brief test, where neither was consistently faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods have the exact same complexity. So, any perceived difference there is entirely personal opinion.

The two methods produce the same result so there is no preference in terms of output.  FYI, the output is `"Test name"`, not `"Test Name"` as you seemed to think.   Generating `"Test Name"` would require a different process.

If you really care about micro-optimizing performance, then the ONLY way to answer all performance questions is to creating one or more meaningful test cases, design a performance test (often using a tool like jsperf) and then measure your test cases in whichever JS engines are important to you and then evaluate the results.

As is always the case with performance issues, premature optimization is foolish because no time should be spent on optimizing performance until you know you actually have a measured performance issue that matters to your application.  Until then, you should write clean, easy to understand and reliable code and spend your development effort in other areas.